# How to access port forward services on gke

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I'm new to gke/gcp and this is my first project. 
I'm setting up istio using https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/quick-start-gke-dm/ tutorial.

I've exposed grafana as shown in the post using:
`kubectl -n istio-system port-forward $(kubectl -n istio-system get pod -l app=grafana -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}') 3000:3000 &`

curl http://localhost:3000/dashboard/db/istio-dashboard
gives me http page on terminal, to access it from the browser I'm using master ip I get after executing `kubectl cluster-info`.

http://{master-ip}:3000/dashboard/db/istio-dashboard is not accessible.

How do I access services using port-forward on gke?

Answer (score 3):

First grab the name of the Pod

```
$ kubectl get pod
```

and then use the port-forward command.

```
$ kubectl port-forward <pod-name> 3000:3000
```

It worked for me, I've found it from this [nice](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-120-networking-basics-3b903f13093a) website also explained on detail how to do it. Hope it can be useful.

Comment: port forwarding is working fine for me. As curl http://localhost:3000/dashboard/db/istio-dashboard is giving the result. Since I'm running this on google kubernetes engine, I want to know how can I access it in browser.
One way I can think of is http://{master-ip}:3000/dashboard/db/istio-dashboard , but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

What (exact) http page is returned by the curl command? Both of these docs [1]&[2] suggest using the url (with localhost) in the browser after setting up a tunnel to Grafana: http://localhost:3000/dashboard/db/istio-dashboard

Alternatively, have you tried with istio-ingressgateway IP address?

[1] https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gke-istio-telemetry-demo#view-grafana-ui

[2] https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/quick-start-gke-dm/#grafana